# Group By either column using C# LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects, group-by

I have a set of Data with columns such as below

```
OffName,RO1,RO2,RO3
```

To explain further i use sample data as below:

```
OffName RO1    RO2   RO3 
A       John   Jack  Rob 
B       Earl   John  Carl 
C       Rob    Chris Kenny 
D       Rodney Carl  Jacob
```

RO stands for Reporting Officer. Each Officer reports to upto 3 RO's.i need to make a report where i need to show a grouping by RO irrespective of the person is RO1 or RO2 or RO3 for the officer..John is RO1 for Officer A and RO2 for Officer B, so when grouped by RO under John i want both Officer A & B to be picked.Same for Carl is RO3 for Officer B and RO2 for Officer D so when grouped by Ro under Carl both Officer B & D to be picked..

So for the above data when grouped by RO's i want the result to be as

```
RO    OffName 
John     A 
         B 
Jack     A 
Rob      A 
         C 
Earl     B 
Carl     B 
         D 
Chris    C 
Kenny    C 
Rodney   D 
Jacob    D
```

Any help would b great

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want grouping or sorting? You talk about grouping, but your desired result indicates no grouping, but rather sorting.

Comment: You have `John B` twice in the results, probably a mistake. Is that linq to sql? linq to objects?

Comment: Hi Mark & Kobe,

Thanks for your replies. I have amended the question above with more details and have corrected d mistakes. Hope my question is clear now.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to ["flatten"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) the problem and then do the group by:

```
    var query = officers.SelectMany(
        x => new[] {
            new { x.Name, RO = x.ReportingOfficer1 },
            new { x.Name, RO = x.ReportingOfficer2 },
            new { x.Name, RO = x.ReportingOfficer3 }
        }
    );
    var grouped = query.GroupBy(y => y.RO);
    foreach (var group in grouped) {
        foreach (var item in group) {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", item.RO, item.Name));
        }
    }
```

Here, I am assuming `officers` is a `IEnumerable<Officer>` where

```
class Officer {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ReportingOfficer1 { get; set; }
    public string ReportingOfficer2 { get; set; }
    public string ReportingOfficer3 { get; set; }
}
```

With your sample data this is my output:

```
John: A
John: B
Jack: A
Rob: A
Rob: C
Earl: B
Carl: B
Carl: D
Chris: C
Kenny: C
Rodney: D
Jacob: D
```

Comment: Hi Jason,

Thanks for your solution and apologize for d late reply. How can do the above without using lambda expression? Any advice would be great.

Thannks