# return different lists for each key

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a table that is parsed in code as a List of string[] (each string[] is a column).

```
Column1| Column2  | Column3
--------+---------+----------
0       | 1       | 8
3       | 2       | 3
5       | 2       | 8
```

Let´s say:

```
string[] column1 = { 0, 3, 5 }
string[] column2 = { 1, 2, 2 };
string[] column3 = { 8, 3, 8 };
List<string[]> table = new List<string[]>() { column1, column2, column3 };
```

I want to select a column (i.e. Column1) groupby Column3, and create a list with each different value in Column3. In other words: group Column1 by column3 and create a Column for each different value of Column3.

The output would be:

```
string[] result1 = { 3 };  // From column3[1] = 3
string[] result2 = { 0, 5 };  // From column3[0] = column3[2] = 8
```

It´s a mix of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947665/group-by-in-linq-query), this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153719/group-by-either-column-using-c-sharp-linq), and Simple 1 from [msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea).
I think about creating a object with column1 and column3, and then do as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186818/unique-list-of-items-using-linq):

```
Class Row { public Row(string row1, string row3); }
List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();
for(int i = 0; i < column1.Length; i++)
{ rows.Add(new Row(Column1[i], Column3[i])); }

var output = rows.GroupBy(row => row.row3).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

But this code code is a bit ugly. Isn´t there something like

```
column3.selectmany(...).GroupBy(row => row.row3).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

I mean, some expression without the need of creating a new class and fill a list of objects... Also, I want as output

```
string[] result1 = { 3 };  // From column3[1] = 3
string[] result2 = { 0, 5 };  // From column3[0] = column3[2] = 8
```

Comment: Note also that *your question should ask a question*. What do you want to know?

Comment: How can I do it. Creating a new class, a list of objects, and then do the groupby it seems poor performance (and not a good code). I think a selectmany operation would be better instead of creating a new class, but I don´t know well how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new type just for grouping you can use the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698.aspx) extension method and an [`anonymous type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397696.aspx) to create the rows.

Grouping is pretty straightforward then. Each group has a key which represents column3 and the `IGrouping` itself is an `IEnumerable` containing the rows from which you select only column 1:

```
var rows = column1.Zip(column3, (c1, c3) => new
{
    Column1 = c1,
    Column3 = c3
});

var output = from row in rows
             group row by row.Column3 into groupedRows
             select groupedRows.Select(r => r.Column1).ToArray();
```

This produces an `IEnumerable<string[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

pescolino's answer using `Zip` is quite nice. If you can't use it (e.g. if you are not on .NET 4.x) then you could use the indexer-overload of `Select` to produce the desired result:

```
var res = col1.Select((fld,idx) => new { Field = fld, Index = idx })
          .GroupBy(entry => col3[entry.Index], entry => entry.Field)
          .Select(grp => grp.ToArray());
```