# Sending jpg file over Http

Tags: c#, http, post, request, jpeg

I'm trying to write a http server which accept images. I managed to transfer txt files or simple text with this way. But when it comes to jpeg file, transfered one becomes unaccessable.

Client side:

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080");
        request.Method = "POST";
        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        request.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
```

Server side:

```
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream,request.ContentEncoding);
        Console.WriteLine("Client data content type {0}", request.ContentType);
        String Data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        byte[] imagebuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, imagebuffer);
```

When i try this with .txt file, byte array's length on each side does not change and server-side file is readable. But with jpg, array length is different. I guess this is causing the problem. What can i do to avoid this? or are there any alternatives?

Edit: Replaced "StreamReader" with "BinaryReader", working fine now. looks like;

```
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding);
        byte[] imagebuffer = reader.ReadBytes((int)request.ContentLength64);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, imagebuffer);
```

Comment: ["John Saunders have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?", where the consensus is "no, they should not"."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214204/return-different-lists-for-each-key#comment21443674_15214204)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTTP post of binary data transfers binary data, not strings. Your server-side code is incorrectly parsing the JPG as some sort of string. Use a Stream object and read the stream into a byte array without the use of the StreamReader object.

Answer (score 0):

You're corrupting the data by encoding it with UTF8.  This is not the place to be using a string.

The server should first verify the ContentLength header, and then read that many bytes using either `BinaryReader.ReadBytes` or `Stream.Read`.  Be sure to look for exceptions though, in case things don't match up.

As another tip, I'd suggest having the server read the data in chunks (a few kilobytes at a time) instead of attempting to store all the data in memory before writing to disk.  You never know how large of a file might be uploaded.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to convert the binary stream to a Base64 encoded string, and then get the bytes from that on the server.

Client

```
var jpgBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
var encodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(jpgBytes);
var encodedBytes = new byte[encodedString.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(encodedString.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
```

Server

```
var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream,request.ContentEncoding); 
var base64String = reader.ReadToEnd();
var jpg = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
```

Comment: This is unnecessary as HTTP supports the transfer of binary files. There should be no base64 involved.